# Question regarding IEEE 754, 64 bits double?

Tags: c, ieee-754

Please take a look at the following content:

[image]

I understand how to convert a double to a binary based on IEEE 754. But I don't understand what the formula is used for.

Can anyone give me an example when we use the above formula, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula that is highlighted in red can be used to calculate the [real number](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Real_number) that a 64-bit value represents when treated as a IEEE 754 double. It's only useful if you want to manually calculate the conversion from binary to the base-10 real number that it represents, such as when verifying the correctness of a C library's implementation of `printf`.

For example, using the formula on `0x3fd5555555555555`, *x* is found to be exactly 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125. That is the real number that `0x3fd5555555555555` represents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  union {
    double d;
    unsigned long long ull;
  } u;

  u.ull = 0x3fd5555555555555L;
  printf("%.55f\n", u.d);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

http://codepad.org/kSithgZQ

**EDIT:** As Olof commented, an IEEE 754 double exactly represents the value *x* in the equation, but not all real numbers are exactly representable. In fact, only a finite number of reals such as 0.5, 0.125, and 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 *are* exactly representable, while the vast majority ([uncountably many](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Uncountable_set)) including 1/3, 0.1, 0.4, and [π](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/%CE%A0) *are not*.

The key to knowing whether a real is exactly-representable as an IEEE 754 double is to calculate the real number's binary representation and write it in [scientific notation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Scientific_notation) (e.g. b1.001×2<sup>-1</sup> for 0.5625). If the number of binary digits to the right of the decimal point excluding trailing zeroes is less than or equal to 52 and the exponent minus one is between -1022 and +1023, inclusive, then the number *is* exactly representable.

Let's go through a couple of examples. Note that it helps to have an arbitrary-precision calculator on hand. I will use [ARIBAS](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~forster/sw/aribas.html).

1. The number 1/64 is 0.015625 in decimal. To calculate its binary representation, we can use ARIBAS' `decode_float` function:

   ```
    ==> set_floatprec(double_float).
   -: 64

   ==> 1/64.
   -: 0.0156250000000000000

   ==> set_printbase(2).
   -: 0y10

   ==> decode_float(1/64).
   -: (0y10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000, 
   -0y1000101)

   ==> set_printbase(10).
   -: 10

   ==> -0y1000101.
   -: -69
   ```

   Thus 1/64 = b0.000001, or b1.0×2<sup>-6</sup> in scientific notation.

   1/64 *is* exactly-representable.
2. The number 1/10 = 0.1 in decimal. To calculate its binary representation:

   ```
   ==> set_printbase(2).
   -: 0y10

   ==> decode_float(1/10).
   -: (0y11001100_11001100_11001100_11001100_11001100_11001100_11001100_11001100, 
   -0y1000011)

   ==> set_printbase(10).
   -: 10

   ==> -0y1000011.
   -: -67
   ```

   So 1/10 = 0.1 = b0.000**1100** (where **bold** represents a repeating digit sequence), or b1.100**1100**×2<sup>-4</sup> in scientific notation.

   1/10 *is not* exactly-representable.

Comment: an excellent answer! Many here at Stackoverflow seem to be under the impression that floating point values are inexact. This is only partially true: when used to represent numbers in the binary space they are completely and absolutely exact, as the example above shows. It's when the decimal space is mapped onto the binary that we get inexactness as the example also shows. To be more precise, it attempts to map an inexact decimal value. Perhaps, for further clarification, you could show how an exact decimal value, such as 0.4, maps to binary and we have all three cases. +1

Comment: @Olof: Thanks for the compliment and suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is to convert the binary representation into a number !

You only need it if you are implementing a floating point unit