# Multiplying two numbers using BigDecimal returns a wrong value

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

Executing the following code:

```
new BigDecimal(0.06 * 3).toString()
```

returns `0.179999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125` instead of `0.18`.

Executing

```
new BigDecimal(0.06).multiply(new BigDecimal(3)).toString()
```

returns the same result.

How is this possible?

Comment: +1 - while the first code's error is quite obvious, the problem with second one is extremely easy to miss during coding and can introduce subtle bugs over and over the code. I'd even go as far as to say that it should be able to generate warnings for it in IDE.

Comment: The 22 upvotes are somewhat confusing, considering the quote *"The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625"* - from the API doc at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-

Comment: @Marco13 if Oracle docs explicitly state that it can be unpredictable (and thus confusing), I'd be inclined to say that having a Q&A mentioning it on SO is even more appropriate, and you've just given another reason why this question deserves an upvote

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're not multiplying two numbers using `BigDecimal`. You're multiplying them using `double` arithmetic, and passing the result to the `BigDecimal` constructor.

You want:

```
new BigDecimal("0.06").multiply(new BigDecimal("3")).toString()
```

Note that you *do* want the values in strings - otherwise you're using the `double` value for 0.06, which isn't exactly 0.06... you've lost information before you start. (You don't really need the string form of 3, but I've done so for consistency.)

For example:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.06));
```

prints

```
0.059999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
```

Comment: Executing `new BigDecimal(0.06).multiply(new BigDecimal(3)).toString()` returns the same result

Comment: @Mark: That's due to a separate problem, which I'll explain in an edit.

Comment: You need the quotes @Mark, since .06 is not exact.

Comment: This is interesting, could you explain why a declared double value of 0.06 isn't really 0.06 ?

Comment: @Mark: It's not exactly representable as a `double`, for all the normal reasons. Think about what the bit pattern would be - it's like trying to represent 1/3 as an exact decimal.

Comment: I think you should use `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.06)` instead of `new BigDecimal(0.06)`

Comment: @dotvav: That's another option, but personally I prefer the explicit nature of using the string representation directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's OK when you work with constants. But when production code is feeding you with `double` already, I feel like it is a waste to format it into `String` before it is parsed back into a `BigDecimal`...

Comment: @dotvav: What do you think `BigDecimal.valueOf` is doing? It's converting it to a string too :) But I'd argue that if you're converting a `double` into a `BigDecimal`, you've quite possibly got serious issues to start with, and you should revisit your design.

Comment: Rather than going through a string representation, I would suggest scaling the value by the desired precision amount, rounding it to a `long`, constructing a `BigInteger` from that, and then the `BigDecimal(BigInteger,scale)` constructor.  For example, to convert a value (e.g. 1.4389) accurate to 0.001, multiply by 1,000 (yielding ~1438.9), round to `long` (1439), convert to `BigInteger`, use that to construct a `BigDecimal` with scale of 3.

Comment: @supercat: We really don't know without more context about where the OP gets the value from. They may not even know the scale they want...

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet writes above, the reason why you are getting `0.179999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125` instead of `0.18` is because `0.06 * 3` is computed as an [IEEE 754 `double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) and then this `double` value is converted to a `BigDecimal`.

Even though `0.06` looks simple enough in source code, the number 0.06 is not exactly representable as an IEEE 754 `double`, so what `0.06` actually represents is an *approximation* of 0.06 equal to 0.059999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375. The number 0.06 in decimal notation is not exactly representable because the number equals 0b0.0**00011110101110000101** in binary notation (where **bold** represents a repeating digit sequence). The computer must truncate this infinite sequence of binary digits, leading to the 0.0599999... approximation.

As I detailed in [my answer to Question regarding IEEE 754, 64 bits double?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113159/196844), you can use [ARIBAS](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~forster/sw/aribas.html)' `decode_float()` function to determine the mantissa and exponent of a floating-point number:

```
==> set_floatprec(double_float).
-: 64

==> set_printbase(2).
-: 0y10

==> decode_float(0.06).
-: (0y11110101_11000010_10001111_01011100_00101000_11110101_11000010_10001111, 
-0y1000100)

==> set_printbase(10).
-: 10

==> -0y1000100.
-: -68

==> set_floatprec(128).
-: 128

==> 1/2**4 + 1/2**5 + 1/2**6 + 1/2**7 + 1/2**9 + 1/2**11 + 1/2**12 + 1/2**13 + 1/2**18 + 1/2**20.
-: 0.11999_98855_59082_03125_00000_00000_00000_00
```

(`**` is exponentiation in ARIBAS).

And we have 0.06 = Σ <sub>i = 0..∞</sub> <sup>0.11999988555908203125</sup> / <sub>2<sup>1 + 20 × i</sup></sub>

You can evaluate this series in a computer algebra system such as Maxima:

```
(%i1) sum ( 0.11999988555908203125 / 2 ^ (1 + 20 * i), i, 0, inf ), simpsum;
(%o1)                                0.06
```

http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r760264757

Answer (score 1):

Working better with `BigDecimal#valueOf`:

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.06).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(3))
```

prints the correct result `0.18`

Comment: +0 - as noted by both Jon Skeet & Java API docs, it will a) generate imprecise double values from the literal, b) convert the number, rounding it in the meantime, to String, c) parse the String into BigDecimal... thus, using quoted String for fractional literals supplied into BigDecimal is usually the best option.